# SQL like Ranking functions in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a way to do ranking functions in Crystal Reports running against a SQL 2000 server?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

I need to return the row number on table A before joining it to table B in Crystal Reports.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can embed 'raw' SQL in a SQL Expression field.  It must be a scalar value, however.  See [Crystal Reports: Using SQL Expression Fields](http://cogniza.com/wordpress/2005/11/07/crystal-reports-using-sql-expression-fields/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [running totals-style or row count formula](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-400955.html) on the data in the report itself. If you need to differentiate between table A and B's data then you can insert a constant into the select statements (do you mean join or union?) and then key on that field in your formula.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm doing a full outer join so the RecordNumber doesn't work since it creates a new RecordNumber for each row after the outer join.  Here's a working example below using SQL Server 2008.  I'd like a new "Rank" or RecordNumber each time there's a new row in table B and only for table B

SELECT     RANK() OVER (ORDER BY B.JobNumber) AS 'Rank', B.JobNumber, B.JobLine
FROM         Jobs A FULL OUTER JOIN
                      JobOutputs C ON A.JobNumber = C.JobNumber FULL OUTER JOIN 
                      JobInputs B ON A.JobNumber = B.JobNumber

.but I want to do this in Crystal Reports.